What is the meaning of "It was just getting to the good bit."?
What is the meaning of "It was just getting to the good bit."?
Does the "the good bit" mean a large amount so that the phrase means "it is starting to rain a lot"?  Is that commonly used phrase in American English for this purpose?
It is from the "Love Is in the Air (2023)" movie.
I screen captured the video for your better understanding the context.
https://youtu.be/RNuywh8CVgE
The script is https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=love-is-in-the-air.
The part of excerpt is as follows.
I care about you.
[electricity crackling]
It was just getting to the good bit.
I'll find some light. There's a lantern

Thank you very much.

This is how it seems to me: A youngish man (with wet hair) is slowly telling a woman (similar age, also with wet hair) that he 'cares about her'. I guess this is B-movie-style Brit understatement. There is a crash of thunder (not electricity crackling), and a third person (an older woman, watching and listening) says 'It was just getting to the good bit.' This is something that Brits might say if something they were watching (e.g. a TV show or movie) was interrupted just before an exciting or touching moment (a 'good bit').

Generally speaking, if watching a movie and you say that, it means the part that is most interesting was about to start. AmE does tend to use part here.

"The good bit" is what we might call the best part of a movie, or a piece of music.
In the clip you shared, the couple are declaring their feelings for each other when suddenly the lights fail and interrupts them. The woman looking on says "it was just getting to the good bit" because she was finding their conversation entertaining as if she was watching a movie and she was lamenting that it was interrupted before it got to "the good bit" (perhaps she thought they might kiss or something).

Thank you Astralbee very much for the answer and Michael Harvey and Lambie for the comments.  How embarrassing it is and shameful I am, to be totally off the mark in guessing the meaning! So, is the bit in this sense chiefly British English?  Thank you.
